# method update in dictionary java

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm working at update method in a dictionary and can't find a solution.
So here I have the dictionary class:

```
 public class Dictionary implements IDictionary{
public class ObjectDictionary{
    //public boolean isFull=false;
    public Object key;
    public Object value;
    public void setValue(Object value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Object getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    public ObjectDictionary(Object k,Object v){
        this.key=k;
        this.value=v;
    }
}
//......(other methods)
public void put(Object k,Object v){ 
        //ObjectDictionary ob = new ObjectDictionary();
        if (elems.length == nrElem){
            resize();
        }
        elems[nrElem] = new ObjectDictionary(k,v);
        elems[nrElem].key=k;
        elems[nrElem].value=v;
        //elems[i].isFull=true;
        nrElem++;

}
public void update(Object k, Object v, Object newV){
    ObjectDictionary ob = new ObjectDictionary(k,v);

    if (lookUp(k) !=null){
       ob.setValue(newV);
    }


}

public Object lookUp(Object k){
    for(int i=0; i<elems.length;i++)
        if(elems[i].key.equals(k)){
            return elems[i].value;     
        }
    return null;
}
}
```

And main:

```
public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args){
    IDictionary d = new Dictionary();
    d.put("a",7);
    d.put("b", 2);
    d.update("a",7, 4);
    //System.out.println(d.size());
    System.out.println(d.lookUp("a"));

}
}
```

I was thinking that maybe is a problem with the lookUp(k) because it returns the value and then it checks if exists or not in dictionary and then can't find anxiously the key but I don't know. What's the problem here?
Also I have tried to replace here:

```
ObjectDictionary ob = new ObjectDictionary(k,v)
```

the v value with 0 but without succeed. Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Why are `key` and `value` of type `Object` and not `String` and `Integer` ? You are passing number as a argument to a function expecting `Object`

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? Do you get error/exception/incorrect result (what result did you expect, why, and what you get instead)?

Comment: I don't receive errors, it only prints me the initial value of a, 7 instead of 4.

Comment: Dictionary class is obsolete. Can you change your code to Map Or Preferences?

Comment: I start working with a dictionary, I'm not going to change my code.

Comment: @ravindra Is this some kind of exercise where you are not allowed to use already existing solutions like Map? Do you have to implement your own directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your not updating on the reference:

```
public void update(Object k, Object v, Object newV){
    ObjectDictionary ob = new ObjectDictionary(k,v);

    if (lookUp(k) !=null){
       ob.setValue(newV);
    }


}
```

try this

```
public Object getEntry(Object k){
    for(int i=0; i<elems.length;i++)
        if(elems[i].key.equals(k)){
            return elems[i];     
        }
    return null;
}
public void update(Object k, Object v, Object newV){

    Object entry = getEntry(k)
    if (entry !=null){
       entry.setValue(newV);
    }


}
```

Comment: Didn't help me.It prints again 7.

Comment: `lookUp(k)` returns value, not `ObjectDictionary` from array on which you could call `setValue`. But main idea is correct: try to find entry from array with selected key, if succeeded update its value, if not put new one (or do nothing depending on what OP needs)

Comment: @Pshemo thanks, i updated the code - didn't realize that there is only the value.